# Android: text not scales smoothly when canvas scaling

Tags: android, canvas

I need implement this feature: text keeps its current size when other elements scaling.
I implement this based on the [SVGMapView](https://github.com/jiahuanyu/SVGMapView) on github, it uses the surfaceview and sets matrix to the canvas. I add the following code to the draw method of the SVGMapLocationOverlay:

```
            textPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            textPaint.setTextSize(80.0f*currentZoom);
            textPaint.setDither(true);
            canvas.drawText("Hello World!", goal[0], goal[1], textPaint);
```

The "80.0f*currentZoom" can keep the text size not change while scaling.

However, the result is not very good, the text jumps while scaling, the video is [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LU3PgH-B-VM).

How to keep the text size not change while scaling

Answer (score 0):

Try use func `invalidate()` as long as you need to scale and measure the time between the `onDraw()` calls.

Also you can consider [ScaleAnimation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/ScaleAnimation.html) where the [Transformation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Transformation.html) contains a matrix.

Comment: We use surface view in the project for some reason. There may be some extra work to do 
 when drawing text with the Canvas from surfaceview.lockCanvas?